# Jasper reports - pagination issues

Tags: jasper-reports

I am having the following issue with paging in Jasper Reports:

I have a report based on the results of a MySql query. Each page corresponds to one row returned from MySql. Basically the text field on the details page prints a long text or a clob.

I have added a page break at the end of the "details" section.

However:

1. If I use "split type" as "Immediate," the page break does not happen for any page that "overflows." In other words, if a text runs over over into two pages, the next record starts on page two itself instead of page three
2. If I use "split type" as "Prevent," an extra page break happens for all the records except for those that have very short text. The extra page causes several blank pages to be printed.

Needless to say, any help would be deeply appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-03-18T17:00:56 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TreatmentPlanNotes" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a6476bf3-e703-4b50-9368-2eec564bb444">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <parameter name="beg_dt" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="end_dt" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="created_dt" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="note" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="patient" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="patient_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="doctor_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band/>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="57" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="14" y="10" width="184" height="30" forecolor="#3D0D0C" uuid="a847deeb-9517-4108-bb2b-9761158446cf"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Treatment Plans:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="185" y="10" width="125" height="30" forecolor="#3D0A08" uuid="bee361db-d322-4d7c-85b9-22c3490ca018">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format($P{beg_dt})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="374" y="10" width="129" height="30" forecolor="#3D0A08" uuid="00abf204-6e5d-4c42-ad41-21fc3eb40247">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format($P{end_dt})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="10" width="30" height="30" forecolor="#3D0A08" uuid="a602d6a4-51ea-47f1-aceb-4a5dcc4ae88d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[to]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="250" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="4" y="8" width="106" height="24" uuid="f78e49a7-3d65-4a68-9dec-b4708a06db72"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{created_dt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="128" y="9" width="112" height="24" uuid="2cfbfba2-e429-415c-8737-05282649b74e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Adobe Garamond Pro Bold" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{patient_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="2" y="43" width="550" height="207" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f15bcb7e-b3d1-4f61-a2ae-63e4807c8a5a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[ITreatUtils.convertHTMLtoPlain($F{note})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="229" y="5" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c19b6d54-120d-449d-a138-f1e6b91641da"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Seeing your JRXML (the detail band at least) might help understand what the problem.  But something else that you can try is to get rid of the break element, and create a group that breaks on each record (use $V{REPORT_COUNT} as group expression for instance) and has the  
isStartNewPage flag set.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using groups - and while there is improvement, there are still a few cases of blank pages once in about 10-15 records. The break happens when the record is about as long as would be accommodated on a page. The page does not happen when the record overflows into another page or when the records fits well within a page. I have added the JRXML.

Comment: The first thing that you can try is to set the group footer and header band heights to 0, and to eliminate the white space from the bottom of the detail band by setting its height to 250.

Comment: Implemented your suggestions. I am now down to just one blank page in 50 records/pages. Which should be acceptable and perhaps not fixable.

As Jasper is only a side project to me, I have to ask you a basic question - how did you conclude that the height of the details band should be 250?

Also, since the question is valid - would you mind accepting the question?

Comment: 250 is the bottom of the lowest element in the detail band: y (43) + height (207) = 250.  JasperReports preserves empty space in bands, so if you want to avoid empty spaces you should not have empty space at the bottom of bands.